# How to make a textbox width look uniform all browsers

Tags: html, css

How to make the text box width look uniform across all browsers?

Here is my code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="att">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class=a /> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class=b /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.a {
  margin:6px -116px 9px -7px;w
  idth:190px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#C2FFC2;
  border:0px
}

.b {
  margin:6px -116px 9px -7px;
  width:190px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#C2FFC2;
  border:0px;
}
```

but in Google Chrome the input box not looking same as in Firefox.

What is causing this difference, and how can I fix it?

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/AJDKa)

Comment: Reset your CSS, to reduce browser inconsistencies

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what looks different? Is it the width, height, or the appearance?

Comment: I check in all browser (for IE I used v10), looks same.  No problem with your code.

Comment: You surely don't want ALL browsers. You know, there are a lot of browsers out there (28 versions of Chrome, Lynx, many versions of Firefox, Opera, Netscape, Mosaik, ...)

Comment: hi ben its width looks diffrent

Answer (score 1):

1. Reset CSS (see [Erik Meyers CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [others](http://www.cssreset.com/))
2. Apply only CSS attributes that are supported by all browsers you care about (see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS))

Comment: I have never heard of that CanIUse site. It's a handy tool when styling a webpage. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the widths, then they should render that way in all browsers unless something else is a factor. There may be widths set on the td  or tr that's effecting it.

Also on another note, you should use a seperate CSS file to style them like this (since your inputs have the same style). So you could do:

```
input[type="type"] { 
  margin: 6px -116px 9px -7px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #C2FFC2;
  border: none; }
```

Another note again, it's a bit of a hack using negative margins unless you're using position absolute, relative or fixed. You'd probably be best positioning these differently or layout them out in a different way.